# What is the maximum allowed size of a URL for a GET request in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

What is the maximum allowed size of a URL for a GET request in IE8?  I have a url that is ~7700 characters that works on all browsers except IE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[2,083](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)

Answer (score 0):

If your url is 7700 characters long you're doing it wrong. Use a post instead.

Comment: GET requests have different semantic meaning than POST.  If you're building a RESTful service that supports complex queries, long GET URLs may be difficult to avoid.

Comment: What kind of data are you submitting and what might be the reason (of the original programmer) for using GET instead of POST?

Comment: It allows you to avoid cross-site scripting prohibitions if done in a script or image tag, for one.

Answer (score 0):

2083
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061010115620AAlvrSF